# Get md5 hash of a file in ftp server using java

Tags: java, ftp, md5

I have wrote a java programme to download a file from FTP server. I need to check are there any corruptions after download the file. so i decided to check **md5** of the file before and after download.

I need to know how can i generate the **md5 hash** of this file, before it downloading ?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I need to generate the `md5 hash` of a file which is stored in a ftp server. not in a local storage.

Comment: You can not calculate a File's MD5 Checksum without reading the file.

Answer (score 2):

calculating md5 can be possible only if you have file content with you so the easiest way to calculate md5 will be to get on the server (e.g. through SSH) calculate the md5 there and compare it with the md5 of the downloaded file.